# Dojo + Highcharts. The X Axis is not alligned when setCategories() is executed

Tags: dojo, highcharts

I am using Dojo and Highcharts, the X axis is not alligned when I use:

```
....xAxis[0].setCategories(...)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xKfU2/6/

In the fiddle, if you comment the first setCategories and you discomment the second one, the X axis is allign, but the chart no. And if you discomment the both of them, you have the both problems.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the problem is occurring, but you can fix it by forcing the x-axis offset like this:

```
xAxis : {
     offset:0
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SSmtN/

I don't think that you should have to do this. Maybe it's a problem related to using dojo ?

Comment: Yes, when I try without Dojo there are no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution too (replace the dojo adapter). I replaced this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.dojotoolkit-fr.org/wp-content/uploads/dojo-adapter.js"></script>
```

for this:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
```

and now goes correctly without doing this:

```
xAxis : {
 offset:0},
```

See --> http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/58-highcharts-standalone-framework