# Dojo + Highcharts: showAxes property moves the x and y axis

Tags: javascript, dojo, highcharts

After solving this problem:

[Dojo + Highcharts. The X Axis is not alligned when setCategories() is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532352/dojo-highcharts-the-x-axis-is-not-alligned-when-setcategories-is-executed)

I get a related error when I add the next code:

```
chart : {
            renderTo : 'comsPerPeriodOfComType',
            type : 'column',
            height : 200,
            **showAxes : true**
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ikercrg/SSmtN/2/

Is this a bug? Can it be solved?

Answer (score 1):

With the Dojo adapter, I have not found any solution, but I replaced this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://www.dojotoolkit-fr.org/wp-content/uploads/dojo-adapter.js"></script>
```

for this:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
```

and now goes correctly.

See --> http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/58-highcharts-standalone-framework